# Android custom textview like whats app

Tags: android, textview

[image]

I want to make a textView exactly like this.Can anyone help??

Comment: you need to create 9.patch image for this

Comment: What have you tried? SO is about posting code and getting help on it, not to build your UI.

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a background image with [9-patch tool](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html), in such a way that the display text would be fit in well and also you need to take care of inner paddings.

**Update:**

Including my comment about why we can't use simple background image?

We can obviously use the simple background but only when you know the size of device in which your application are going to use "only", but in android no one can be sure about the size as it's coming into the variety of resolutions and display sizes. So if you would want to provide the image compatibility to all the sizes and resolutions then prepare such background using 9-patch tool

Comment: can we not use at the place of 9-patch tool image simple background

Comment: @amitsharma sorry I didn't get!

Comment: you just write here to advice 9-patch tool image should use here at background at textview i am saying or asking you can we not use simplebackground to set background image at textview Like in question

Comment: Like this  <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/tvi"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        />

Comment: We can obviously use the simple background but only when you know the size of device in which your application are going to use "only", but in android no one can be sure about the size as it's coming into the variety of resolutions and display sizes. So if you would want to provide the image compatibility to all the sizes and resolutions then prepare such background using 9-patch tool